# Talk to Google Talk/Hangout contacts and Skype/MSN contacts from one client

Tags: microsoft-outlook, skype, windows-live-messenger, google-talk, xmpp

I have some friends only available on Google Talk and some others who use Skype. I use the old Talk client because the new Hangouts client requires a Chrome installation.

Now, theoretically, Microsoft integrated Google Talk into Outlook.com. This means that I should be able to chat with Google Talk contacts from a web browser in outlook.com. This sometimes works, but I cannot see all the contacts, only some of them. This may be because Google dropped something called XMPP interoperability with the introduction of Hangouts. **Does Outlook.com use XMPP to connect to Google Talk?** If it does this means that their GTalk support will cease to work.

If this works, should Google Talk contacts appear in the desktop Skype client too? It has an option called "Show Outlook contacts" but that does nothing in my case.

In the most likely case that I can't get this to work,

- is Microsoft planning to add Google Talk support to the desktop version of Skype?
- is there a reliable (non-adware, non-malware, widely-used) client that can talk to both worlds?